# Dynamic tableViewCellHeights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView Which include 3 cells. A title, Description and Attach cell. I would like the descriptionCell to be dynamic, so that attachcell bottom touches the UIKeyBoard how can i make such an implementation? at the moment i've found the frame of the KeyBoard by using NSNotifications. TitleCell height is 50 and attachCell height is 40.

How can i make sure that on the different devices that the attachCell bottom is at the same position of the top of UiKeyBoard?

I do not mind that the answer is in Obj-C.

[image]

## ViewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "New"
    self.tableView?.scrollEnabled = false
    self.tableView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DescriptionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DescriptionViewCell")
    self.tableView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "AttachViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AttachViewCell")
    self.tableView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TitleViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TitleViewCell")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

## KeyBoardWillShow

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()

}
```

## heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0  {
        return 50
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {

        return 150

    } else {
        return 40
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Warning: The way you put it, you may ending up fighting UIKit all day long. Take into consideration that you will have to customize this solution for different devices' screen sizes and orientation.*

Having said that, this guide should point you to the right direction: [Managing the keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html).

The `- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {` together with `[scrollView setContentOffset` should provide a solution. It also implies plenty of `if, else if, else` statements.

**My humble advice:** Rather than focussing on aesthetics think usability.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could u explain the scrollView solution since my view contain a UITableView and not scrollView

Comment: Does the keyboard push the tableview up at the present? If not, make your description cell taller (say 250 points) and you'll see the scrollview in action. What I meant is to set a negative offset for the scrollview. It isn't an elegant solution though.